# Facebook oauth cancel

Tags: facebook, spring, oauth

I have an application that goes through the facebook oauth process, but when I select "cancel" during the process is takes me to an invalid URL

```
"www.mydomain.com/app/connect/facebook?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied#_=_"
```

Can this be fixed on facebooks side or do I have to add code to handle this?
What is the most efficient way to fix this problem?

Comment: What is _invalid_ about that URL …?

Answer (score 0):

See the bottom of the paragraph "Cancelled login" of  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/#login to check for details...